# python spider for IPMI webside

Tags: python, web-crawler

I try to use python spider to get get mac address , LAN mac address or others information.  so I import the requests modules into python
below is my script

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.post('http://192.168.5.45/cgi/login.cgi', headers={'User-Agent': 'Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1'},  data={'name':'ADMIN','pwd':'ADMIN'},timeout=10)
    respons = s.post("http://192.168.5.45/cgi/url_redirect.cgi?url_name=sys_info", headers={'User-Agent': 'Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1', "Cookie":"langSetFlag=0; language=English; SID=ytswdoamcdfxxufl; mainpage=system; subpage=top"}, data={'name':'ADMIN','pwd':'ADMIN'}, timeout=10)
    print (respons.text)
```

but I don't get the html with mac address, any ideals for this question?

by the way, I know how to get those information by ipmitool, but at this moment, I want to try python.

Thanks

RT.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is my mistake, actually, I should use get to replace post on the 4th line. then all looks good and I can use 're' to grub the information that I want.
Thanks

RT